# AngularJs Sorting all records across all pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

hey everyone am trying to make a sort to all my records when i use the sort key and function am getting a sort on only on the current page i didn't get it why it sort only in the current page here's my code :

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-click="sort('cin')">Cin <span
                                class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='cin'"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('nom')">Nom <span
                                class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='nom'"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('prenom')">Prenom <span
                                class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='prenom'"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('email')">Email <span
                                class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='email'"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('adresse')">Adresse <span
                                class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='adresse'"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>index</th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('role_name')">Roles <span
                                class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='adresse'"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr
                            dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:5">
                            <td>{{user.cin}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.prenom}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.adresse}}</td>
                            <td>{{$index}}</td>
                            <td><table>
                                    <tr ng-repeat=" role in user.roles">
                                        <td>{{role.role_name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>

                            <td>
                                <button ng-click="edit(user)" class="btn btn-warning btnt"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td><button ng-click="supp(user.cin)"
                                    class="btn btn-danger btnt">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                </button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

and here's my js code :

```
$scope.sort = function(keyname){
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   // set the sortKey to the param passed
        console.log("keyname="+$scope.keyname);
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; // if true make it false and
                                            // vice versa
    }
```

ᐧThanks to any help

Comment: What do you mean with all pages?

Comment: Have a look at ng-table

Comment: Where do you get `$scope.users` from?

Comment: It sounds like you're not using angular as a SPA and running separate HTML pages instead. If that's the case, angular, your module, your controllers, etc. are reloaded on each page or are you referring to pages within the table itself?

Comment: i have a pagination my sort only works for the current page not all

Comment: Does your pagination come from a call to a server?

Comment: no am using this https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is sorting the results in controller itself.

```
$filter('orderBy')($scope.users, 'cin');
```

where $scope.users is what you are repeating and cin is your criteria of sort.
Hope this help!

Comment: Down vote! if anyone could explain so that I also know.

Comment: thanks for answering me this doesn't solve my issue  ps  you have to know that i didn't made that down vote .

Comment: @KamelMili - there was one downvote earlier by someone so wanted to know the reason. I think you need to write custom filter where your filter will get the complete data that is coming from the your backend and then sort it. Paginaiton directives consider data that is currently on the screen so that is why only current data set is sorted and not everything.